# What are these black tapes in green screening?

Tags: greenscreen, tracking

[image]

In some 'making of' green screening videos, I saw these black tapes on the actors. What are these for?

Comment: related: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/5541/what-kind-of-camera-do-i-need-to-record-a-moving-object-in-order-to-do-motion-tr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume these are *home made motion markers* in order to track the motion of the head in the shot. This is useful for adding other objects (or images) to the object, therefore the technique is called **object tracking**.

**Note:** The example given is only useful for 2d tracking, because most 3d solvers needs a minumium of 8 tracking markers around the object (in each frame).